# GDAL/Shapely how to use representative_point()

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, shapely

I am trying to create a single point inside each polygon of a dataset using shapely's representative_point() function. According to the documentation [here](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.representative_point) it is called on a geometry object, so it should work similarly to calling Centroid() on a geometry object. However, when I try to do so I get:

AttributeError: 'Geometry' object has no attribute 'representative_point()'.

```
import shapely
...

    for bld in xrange(bld_layer.GetFeatureCount()):
        bld_feat = bld_layer.GetFeature(bld)
        bld_geom = bld_layer.GetGeometryRef()
        bld_point = bld_geom.representative_point()
        ...
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments and after more searching a combination of Fiona and Shapely ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/223769/83494)) seems to work:

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping

src = r'C:\data\segments.shp' 
out = r'C:\data\segments_points.shp' 
data = fiona.open(src, 'r')
data_schema = data.schema
data_schema['geometry'] = 'Point'
with fiona.open(out, 'w', crs = data.crs, driver = data.driver, schema = data_schema) as dst:
    for f in data:
        point = shape(f['geometry']).representative_point()
        f['geometry'] = mapping(point)
        dst.write(f)
```

Comment: You are mixing GDAL and Shapely. A GDAL Geometry is not a Shapely geometry.

Comment: If you want to mix GDAL/OGR and Shapely you need specifically use 'loads' method from **shapely.wkt** python module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mix GDAL/OGR and Shapely you need specifically use 'loads' method from **shapely.wkt** python module. For instance, next code does the job:

```
from osgeo import ogr
from shapely.wkt import loads

path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp'

dataSource = ogr.Open(path, 1)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

for feature in layer:
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    print loads(geom.ExportToWkt()).representative_point()

dataSource = None
```

After running it, it was printed at Python Console each **representative_point** in WKT format.

[image]

Comment: I found this method as well via the link below. However, I wasn't able to implement it thus I switched to the one above. But thank you for adding another option. link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5405/using-shapely-translating-between-polygons-and-multipolygons?rq=1